# Asking array as input in UDF

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and I want to create as user defined function using few parameters which are:

1. an array having 1 row and n column
2. an array having n rows and m columns * N & M are variables ranging from 0 to say 32
3. an integer value

And function multiplies all three to give an output

```
Function VArray( Aarray() as variant, Barray() as variant, C as long) as Variant
```

I want to know syntax for asking input for the two arrays from users so that function may be executed.

Comment: Did you [investigate](https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-inputbox/) something yourself?

Comment: Seems like it would be simplest to ask your users to select ranges on a worksheet as inputs

Comment: Any links where I could find some material on same

Comment: Create your UDF and the user can call it from a worksheet - just like any other Excel function.